# Text wrapping issues inside of a floated div

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting the text on the right side of the box to wrap into two lines when the screen width is too narrow to show all of the text on one line. Instead, the entire right side bumps down below the left.

How do I get this to just wrap to two lines? Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orbLv5op/)

```
.box {
    height: 80px;
    clear: both;
}
.left {
    width: 90px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.right {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: remove `float:left` from `.right` http://jsfiddle.net/haxxxton/orbLv5op/1/

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do on the .right is add a width maybe of like 40% or so and it should just text wrap as the pages gets smaller.

```
.right {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments by [haxxxton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648350/haxxxton), removing the `float` from `.right` will result in the [desired behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/haxxxton/orbLv5op/1/). Floated elements will break line if there is no space.